# Exception bridge module null does not conform to RCTBridgeModule was dispatchViewManagerCommand Error after Upgrading to react native 0.71.16 to 0.72

Tags: android, ios, react-native

i faced this error after Upgrading from react native 0.71.16 to 0.72
Exception bridge module null does not conform to RCTBridgeModule was dispatchViewManagerCommand not target UIManager with params ( 85, reset, ()))

- the issue is on ios, android
- I face this issue when the app start
- the app is working fine in ios, android

please see the attachmentc media.

[image]

Comment: does anyone have a clue here?

Comment: thank god i managed to solve this issue if anyone wondering it was a problem with compatibility with lottie-react-native & lottie-ios libraries versions